# Java Sudoku Solver choice elimination bug

Tags: java, debugging, sudoku

I'm using a four dimensional array write a Sudoku solver in Java, where the dimensions describe the location of the cell on the board and the values assigned to them are the possible numbers that the cell can be. [Sudoku Wikipedia, for reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku)

I have written methods for printing a Unicode art representation of the board for clarity, as well as a method to print all of the choices for each cell on the board. These methods work. However, my method to eliminate singletons from other cells in the single's row, column, and box does not work as intended (removing from unknown cells all known cells in the same row/column/box). Note that the top left cell (`choiceArray[0][0][0][0]`) should be the string `467` but is instead `23478`. Here is the code I wrote. Sudoku boards are entered as 81-character strings, where 0's represent empty cells in the initial board.

(In addition to answering this question, stylistic/procedural advice from more experienced programmers than myself would be appreciated, as I'm very much a beginner)

```
public class SudokuSolver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String initialBoard = "020501090800203006030060070001000600540000019002000700090030080200804007010907060";

        //Parsing the input to make sure that it is valid
        if (!(initialBoard.matches("[0-9]+") && initialBoard.length() == 81)) {
            System.err.println("Input board was not valid.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        //Generating the sudoku board
        printBoard(initialBoard);

        //Generating an array for the given information
        String[][][][] choiceArray = new String[3][3][3][3];
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { //row of box
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) { //column of box
                for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++) { //row in box
                    for(int l = 0; l < 3; l++) { //column in box
                        int cellNumber = 27 * i + 3 * j + 9 * k + l;
                        char cellContents = initialBoard.charAt(cellNumber);

                        if(cellContents == '0') {
                            choiceArray[i][j][k][l] = "123456789";
                        }
                        else {
                            choiceArray[i][j][k][l] = Character.toString(cellContents);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Removing singletons
        while(!(puzzleIsSolved(choiceArray))) {
            boolean boardChanges = false;

            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { //row of box
                for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) { //column of box
                    for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++) { //row in box
                        for(int l = 0; l < 3; l++) { //column in box
                            if(choiceArray[i][j][k][l].length() == 1) {
                                String solvedCell = choiceArray[i][j][k][l];

                                //Removing choice from row (i, k constant)
                                for(int a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
                                    for(int b = 0; b < 3; b++) {
                                        if(a != j && b != l) {
                                            if(choiceArray[i][a][k][b].contains(solvedCell)) {
                                                choiceArray[i][a][k][b] = removeChoice(choiceArray[i][a][k][b], solvedCell);
                                                boardChanges = true;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                //Removing choice from column (j, l constant)
                                for(int a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
                                    for(int b = 0; b < 3; b++) {
                                        if(a != i && b != k) {
                                            if(choiceArray[a][j][b][l].contains(solvedCell)) {
                                                choiceArray[a][j][b][l] = removeChoice(choiceArray[a][j][b][l], solvedCell);
                                                boardChanges = true;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                //Removing choice from box (i, j constant)
                                for(int a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
                                    for(int b = 0; b < 3; b++) {
                                        if(a != i && b != j) {
                                            if(choiceArray[a][b][k][l].contains(solvedCell)) {
                                                choiceArray[a][b][k][l] = removeChoice(choiceArray[a][b][k][l], solvedCell);
                                                boardChanges = true;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if(!boardChanges) {
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(choiceArray[0][0][0][0]);
        //expected: 467
        //actual:   23478
    }

    //Printing the current state of the sudoku
    public static void printBoard(String input) {
        String rowA = "╔═══╤═══╤═══╦═══╤═══╤═══╦═══╤═══╤═══╗";
        String rowB = "╟───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╢";
        String rowC = "╠═══╪═══╪═══╬═══╪═══╪═══╬═══╪═══╪═══╣";
        String rowD = "╚═══╧═══╧═══╩═══╧═══╧═══╩═══╧═══╧═══╝";

        input = input.replaceAll("0", " ");

        System.out.println(rowA);
        for(int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
            for(int box = 0; box < 3; box++) {
                System.out.print("║");
                for(int cell = 0; cell < 3; cell++) {
                    System.out.print(" " + input.charAt(9 * row + 3 * box + cell) + " ");
                    if(cell != 2) {
                        System.out.print("│");
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("║");
            if(row % 3 == 2 && row != 8) {
                System.out.println(rowC);
            }
            else if(row != 8){
                System.out.println(rowB);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(rowD);
            }
        }
    }

    //Print all possible choices in all cells in sudoku (good for debugging)
    public static void printAllChoices(String[][][][] choiceArray) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { //row of box
            for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++) { //row in box
                for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) { //column of box
                    for(int l = 0; l < 3; l++) { //column in box
                        int cellNumber = 27 * i + 3 * j + 9 * k + l + 1;
                        System.out.println(cellNumber + ": " + choiceArray[i][j][k][l]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Check if all cells only have one choice left
    public static boolean puzzleIsSolved(String[][][][] choiceArray) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                    for(int l = 0; l < 3; l++) {
                        if(choiceArray[i][j][k][l].length() > 1) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    //Removing choice from cell
    public static String removeChoice(String initialChoices, String choiceToRemove) {
        String finalChoices = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < initialChoices.length(); i++) {
            if(initialChoices.charAt(i) != choiceToRemove.charAt(0)) {
                finalChoices += initialChoices.charAt(i);
            }
        }

        return finalChoices;
    }
}
```

Comment: "does not work" **HOW**?

Comment: _does not work as intended_ So what does it do then? Is there an error you can show us? Please read this as well http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @user1875195 I updated it. Can you take a look at it now?

Comment: My suggestion would be to create a Cell class that holds the possible values and the correct value.  Then you would create and update a 2 dimensional array of Cell instances, rather than a 4 dimensional array.  It's too easy to lose track of which cell is which with a 4 dimensional array.